# Color individual markers based on corresponding hex codes in dataframe matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, hex, marker, scatter

I have a simple dataframe `data` that has columns that represent the sample ID `region`, the quantity I want to plot `hotspot_ratio`, and two separate columns with hex codes `hex` and `hex_2`. I want the markers to be colored based on each datapoint's corresponding combination of the two hex codes.

I learned from this page:(https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_fillstyle_reference.html)
that two colors can be assigned to singular markers. I would like to implement something simple like this, but I'm unclear about how to use `dict` to assign `color` and `markerfacecoloralt` for each datapoint.

Here is my current code that basically just plots square markers with the fill color corresponding to the data points' value using `cmap`. The x-axis doesn't matter to me. I just need the points to spread out enough so labels can be read and the points are roughly plotted in ascending order. I used some tricks to do this, but I'm also aware that this probably isn't the best way to show this data. However, if I can get the color-coding with the 2 hex values that I want, that will really help. Thanks in advance for your patience with my crappy novice-level code!

```
    fig , ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (14,12))

    marker_style = dict(color='tab:blue', marker='s',
                markersize=15, markerfacecoloralt='tab:red')


    #c sequence
    c = data['hotspot_ratio'].dropna()
    # plasma = cm.get_cmap('plasma',5)
    # cmap = plasma(np.linspace(0,1,10))

    x = data['hotspot_ratio'].dropna()
    y = data['hotspot_ratio'].dropna()

    xr = [i+random.uniform(0,0.00035) for i in x]
    # yr = [i+random.uniform(0.00001,0.0001) for i in y]
    # xr = x
    yr = y
    n = data['name'].dropna()
    r = data['region'].dropna()

    p = ax1.scatter(xr,yr,marker = 's',edgecolor = 'k',s = 400,c=c,cmap = 'coolwarm')
    ax1.set_xlim(np.min(xr)-0.000035,np.max(xr)+0.000035)
    ax1.set_ylim(data['hotspot_ratio'].min()-0.0001,data['hotspot_ratio'].max()+0.00003)
    ax1.tick_params(which = 'minor')
    ax1.tick_params(left = True, bottom = False, labelbottom=False, labelsize = 14)
    ax1.minorticks_on()
    plt.tick_params(axis='x',which='both',bottom=False,top=False,labelbottom=False)
    ax1.grid(True,axis = 'y', which = 'major', color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=1)
    ax1.grid(True,axis = 'y', which = 'minor', color='grey', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)
    ax1.set_ylabel('Hotspot Ratio (Hotspot area/total area)',size = 16, fontweight = 'bold')


    # zip joins x and y coordinates in pairs
    # for i, txt in enumerate(n):

    #     plt.annotate(txt, # this is the text
    #                  (xr[i],yr[i]), # this is the point to label
    #                  textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
    #                  xytext=(0,20), # distance from text to points (x,y)
    #                  ha='center',
    #                  rotation = 90-(random.uniform(0,8))) # horizontal alignment can be left, right or center

    for i, txt in enumerate(r):
        plt.annotate(txt, # this is the text
             (xr[i],yr[i]), # this is the point to label
             textcoords="offset points", # how to position the text
             xytext=(0,-51), # distance from text to points (x,y)
             ha='center',va = 'center',
             rotation = 90) # horizontal alignment can be left, right or center

    ax1.hlines(regions['hotspot_ratio']['Atqasuk'],np.min(xr)-0.000035,np.max(xr)+0.000035,color = '#C7D8F0',
       linewidth = 4,zorder = 0)
    ax1.annotate('Atqasuk',(np.min(xr),regions['hotspot_ratio']['Atqasuk']+0.00001),size = 13,fontweight = 'bold')

    ax1.hlines(regions['hotspot_ratio']['Utqiagvik'],np.min(xr)-0.000035,np.max(xr)+0.000035,color = '#C7D8F0',
       linewidth = 4,zorder = 0)
    ax1.annotate('Utqiagvik',(np.min(xr),regions['hotspot_ratio']['Utqiagvik']-0.000015),size = 13,fontweight = 'bold')

    ax1.hlines(regions['hotspot_ratio']['Innoko'],np.min(xr)-0.000035,np.max(xr)+0.000035,color = '#4E68D8',
       linewidth = 4,zorder = 0)
    ax1.annotate('Innoko',(np.max(xr)-0.000035,regions['hotspot_ratio']['Innoko']+0.00001),size = 13,fontweight = 'bold')

    ax1.hlines(regions['hotspot_ratio']['Mackenzie Delta'],np.min(xr)-0.000035,np.max(xr)+0.000035,color = '#B3CDFB',
       linewidth = 4,zorder = 0)
    ax1.annotate('Mackenzie Delta',(np.min(xr),regions['hotspot_ratio']['Mackenzie Delta']-0.000015),size = 13,fontweight = 'bold')

    ax1.hlines(regions['hotspot_ratio']['Minto Flats'],np.min(xr)-0.000035,np.max(xr)+0.000035,color = '#B30427',
       linewidth = 4,zorder = 0)
    ax1.annotate('Minto Flats',(np.min(xr),regions['hotspot_ratio']['Minto Flats']+0.00001),size = 13,fontweight = 'bold')

    ax1.hlines(regions['hotspot_ratio']['Old Crow Flats'],np.min(xr)-0.000035,np.max(xr)+0.000035,color = '#8EB0FF',
       linewidth = 4,zorder = 0)
    ax1.annotate('Old Crow Flats',(np.max(xr)-0.0001,regions['hotspot_ratio']['Old Crow Flats']-0.000015),size = 13,fontweight = 'bold')

    ax1.hlines(regions['hotspot_ratio']['YK Delta'],np.min(xr)-0.000035,np.max(xr)+0.000035,color = '#F5C2AA',
       linewidth = 4,zorder = 0)
    ax1.annotate('YK Delta',(np.min(xr),regions['hotspot_ratio']['YK Delta']+0.00001),size = 13,fontweight = 'bold')

    ax1.hlines(regions['hotspot_ratio']['Yellowknife/Daring L.'],np.min(xr)-0.000035,np.max(xr)+0.000035,color = '#9CBDFF',
       linewidth = 4,zorder = 0)
    ax1.annotate('Yellowknife/Daring L.',(np.max(xr)-0.000155,regions['hotspot_ratio']['Yellowknife/Daring L.']+0.00001),size = 13,fontweight = 'bold')

    ax1.hlines(regions['hotspot_ratio']['Yukon Flats'],np.min(xr)-0.000035,np.max(xr)+0.000035,color = '#80A3FA',
       linewidth = 4,zorder = 0)
    ax1.annotate('Yukon Flats',(np.max(xr)-0.000075,regions['hotspot_ratio']['Yukon Flats']-0.000015),size = 13,fontweight = 'bold')

    ax1.hlines(regions['hotspot_ratio']['Toolik/Sag River'],np.min(xr)-0.000035,np.max(xr)+0.000035,color = '#455DCE',
       linewidth = 4,zorder = 0)
    ax1.annotate('Toolik/Sag River',(np.max(xr)-0.0001,regions['hotspot_ratio']['Toolik/Sag River']-0.000015),size = 13,fontweight = 'bold')

    #plt.savefig('HotspotRatiosbyarea.png',dpi = 400)
```

[image: mat]

Comment: Hey! Is it possible for you to provide a [Minmal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), with some dummy data? It would really help people to be able to help you.

Comment: I think it would make more sense to provide an MRE if my code had a bug or wasn't working. My problem is I don't even know how to approach what I'm trying to do. In the simplest terms, I'm trying to make a scatter plot whose markers are filled with colors that correspond to multiple hex codes that are unique to each data point in the data frame.

Comment: If you provide a MRE/toy example, people can play with it in order to provide you a solution.